# How to use "WHERE" and also "WHERE NOT EXISTS" in the same query and table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to add both `WHERE` and `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in same query. Below mentioned query1 is working fine, but it returns all the t1 data which does not belong to company1. So I tried query2, but no luck. How can I get the desired result?

1.

```
select * from t1 where not exists
(select * from t2 inner join t3 on(t3._id = t2.department_id)where t2.category_id = t1._id AND t3._id = 27 AND t3.company_id = 1) 
 ORDER BY "ctsName"
```

2.

```
select * from t1 where company_id = 1 AND where not exists
(select * from t2 inner join t3 on(t3._id = t2.department_id)where t2.category_id = t1._id AND t3._id = 27 AND t3.company_id = 1) 
 ORDER BY "ctsName"
```

Comment: You must write WHERE only once. All checking conditions in this sections are linked using any logical operators. So you must write like `... where company_id = 1 AND not exists (select * from t2 ...`

Comment: To clarify a bit - the first query consists of a main query with a `WHERE` clause, and within that a sub-query with its own, completely separate `WHERE` clause. That's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` is a separator, not an operation , the bit after `WHERE` describes the rows you want to see in the result.

To apply two conditons use `AND` or `OR` to combine them.

```
select * from t1 
where not exists (select * from t2 inner join t3 on(t3._id = t2.department_id)
  AND  t2.category_id = t1._id AND t3._id = 27 AND t3.company_id = 1) 
ORDER BY "ctsName"
```